# Скачет содержимое flex

Tags: css, flexbox

Извиняюсь. Переделал немного.

Вот пример https://codepen.io/gluhovalexey/pen/OBjzGY

Здесь есть шапка и элемент из 3 частей, который включает списки ul слева и справа и div с контентом посередине, находящиеся в flex-contaner

Суть вопроса если убрать элемент со списками ul, то ширина шапки уменьшится.
Тоесть если со страницы сайта в которой есть ul как на примере перейти на другую, где списков нет, то шапка сайта и другие постоянные элементы будут "прыгать" из за изменения размеров.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div  class="flex-row header">
        <img src="https://d.radikal.ru/d17/1810/b9/7bd548daa75f.png">
        <img src="https://d.radikal.ru/d17/1810/b9/7bd548daa75f.png">
        <img src="https://d.radikal.ru/d17/1810/b9/7bd548daa75f.png">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row content">
        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт a</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт b</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт c</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт d</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт e</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт f</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт j</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт h</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
            Какой то контент посередине

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <ul>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 5</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 6</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 7</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="" target="_blank">Пункт 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
.header {
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.header img {
    width: 32%;
    margin: 1px;
    height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 50px
}

.content {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
}

.content .left {
    flex: 2;
    width: 20%;

}

.content .center {
    flex: 4;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.content .right {
    flex: 2;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Изменил пример чтобы было понятно, что где и чтобы не приглядываться. Полчаса читаю вопрос и код и так и не понял в чем проблема.

Comment: Исправьте вопрос, ничего не понятно.

Comment: Без стилей ничем не поможем, по сути родителю накинте `justify-content: space-between`

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю понял что вы хотели:
https://codepen.io/Rusic/pen/EdvQee

Суть в том, что нужно ограничить рост и уменьшение флексов:
краток это `flex: 0 0 60%` но ранее с этим были проблемы в записе по порядку:

```
flex-grow: 0
flex-shrink: 0
flex-basis: 60%
```

Comment: Rusla Semenov, не помогло. ширина .flex-container меняется и тянет соответственно за собой элементы внутри

Comment: Ну так правильно, родитель то резиновый, задавайте тогда размеры не в % а пикселях, или жёстко задайте размер родителя

Answer (score 0):

Видимо происходит это из за того, что контент меняется динамически в теге . С самого начала надо было сказать что делается все в Angular.
Создал две статические странички одна с шапкой и колонками, другая с шапкой без колонок, ничего не прыгает, ширина контейнера всегда одна.

Comment: А ларчик просто открывался... Всё из за того, что справа появлялась полоса прокрутки из за увеличения страницы по горизонтали.